# How one would get live, video frames from a device camera in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, video

So, I am prototyping an application that is similar to the popular app [SnapChat](https://www.snapchat.com/). If you are familiar with the app, a large part of it's user interface consists of a live video feed from the camera. This is not in an operating system video capture window, no, this has the video, with UI elements overlayed upon it.

I can't code in native to save my life, so I develop my apps in PhoneGap. Unfortunately, after all the usual Googling, I still haven't found an answer. I am looking for a way to capture video frames and render them in the DOM, live, from the device camera.

I couldn't find a plugin for this, is it capable with the PhoneGap APIs?

Comment: "would anyone be willing to write a plugin?" is not the kind of question SO is designed for. It sounds like you should hire a developer.

Comment: This is not possible with PhoneGap APIs. It would have to be a plugin or full native. As for someone making a plugin, the plugin would have to be very specifically built (not really reusable) or extremely complex. An app of this complexity is not well suited for PhoneGap

Comment: Understood @Jordan, edited. Thank you for your opinion Dawson.

Comment: @SamWeaver did you get any solution to capture video frames?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML Media Capture for the following devices

> Android 3.0 browser
>   Chrome for Android (0.16)
>   Firefox Mobile
>   10.0 iOS6 Safari and Chrome (partial support)

From my naive glancing it looks like it kicks the user over to the native device video capturerer and returns the video once the user is done. It looks like you can't use custom overlays in the video capture UI.

For better control you can use WebRTC which is supported by the following devices

> Chrome 21
>   Android 4.4
>   Opera 18
>   Firefox 17

http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

With this you can embed the capture area within the DOM and mess with it as you see fit. 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

I just tried out [this demo](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/) mentioned on the html5rocks page on my galaxy note 3 and both the front and back camera worked

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but it does not work on iOS. Darn!

Comment: @SamWeaver added some info for ios, though it may not meet your requirements